# Rails use different layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know rails uses the default application.html.erb. I have a profile and on my profile I have videos, photos etc, how can I separate my homepage(Home, About, Signup, Login) from the actual application? The problem I am having is when a user tries to signup rails throws an error

```
Couldn't find Site with subdomain =
```

That is because I have not created a subdomain nor site since I am unable to sign up to create one.

How can i tell rails to use application.html for pages like home, about, signup, etc and use home.hmtl.erb for the profile pages and videos etc?

Comment: I've run into this problem in a few apps. My solution is to create a new template in `app/views/layouts` like so `controller_name.html.erb`. The directory containing your resources (e.g pages) should match the name of the template `pages/`. You _could_ also use different stylesheets and js for that particular controller-specified in the template like usual. When you route to the resources object (say `pages/home`) you should see the template and resource. I can turn it into an answer if this is actually helpful. good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a controller called home or something similar.  Then in the controller call:

```
layout :layout_name
```

you may need to create an index.html for it to not throw an error as well

Comment: home is fine but the signup, register, login etc are the pages that I need to change the layout on but I am not sure which controller controls them. I tried user_controller and did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a session controller? It is whatever controller is called when the user goes to the sign in page.  If you don't know, look at the link to the sign in page. It should be in the format of
    http://domain.com/controller/action
for general actions

Answer (score 1):

You can add layout and its name when rendering action for each action where new lay out is required or u can create set layout method by default is set application and for special action load specific layout.